# Can't play video in JWPlayer in IOS 7 app, 6.1 works fine

Tags: ios, ios7, html5-video, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I'm trying to do something pretty basic here. I can't get JWPlayer to even play in an IOS 7 app. When I run it in the simulator as IOS 6.1 it can play just fine. I started with a much more complicated app but then started over with just a single page application. That single page contains one web view which takes the entire space. I'm loading a URL into the web view. That URL that is being loaded is an external page which contains the player. The player loads just fine. I don't get any errors. However, when trying to click play on IOS 7 nothing happens. Like I said, if I switch the simulator to IOS 6.1, I can click play and it works great.

I'm not trying to autostart the video. I'm not trying to play a flash file (it's an .mp4). I'm using the latest version of JWPlayer 6.8. Did something change in IOS 7 regarding HTML5 video player support?

UPDATE: I tried a web view that had just a  tag and was able to play the video successfully in IOS 7.

ANOTHER UPDATE: I just tried the exact same code as an iPad app IOS 7 and it works! What is going on here?

Comment: Have you tried with just a <video> tag inside of the webview as well?

Comment: I just tried just the <video> tag in the web view and I was able to play the video without any problems.

Comment: Okay, it might have to do with how we are implementing the player now on iOS. Ever since 6.6+, we render out our own skins instead of falling back to <video>. You can test with 6.5 for example by using this call - http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/5/jwplayer.js, just replace the 5 with different numbers to test them. Keep in mind we have not tested the JW Player for use inside of a webview.

Comment: I tried 6.2 - 6.8 and they all seem to have the same problem. I can provide the link to my sample app on GitHub if you'd like. Is there another way to use JWPlayer in IOS? I've not seen anything about an IOS SDK.

Comment: There is not a SDK for iOS. We really have not tested the player in this set up before.

Comment: Is this something you would consider investigating? Apps are definitely a huge part of the mobile landscape. We love JWPlayer and use it for all of our platforms - desktop, mobile web, apps. We have an Ads license. I'm not sure how else you can use JWPlayer in an app. If there is no SDK then the only other option is to use a web view.

Comment: We might look into an SDK in the future. We have a beta for Android, and I believe iOS is something we are also looking into.

Comment: Glad to hear an SDK may be on the roadmap. I was more referring to looking into why this broke with the latest release of IOS 7 (iPhone only) and web views.

Comment: I am not sure why it broke here...again, we have never tested this scenario in the past...

Comment: Can any one send me link for JWPlayer SDK for iOS ?